# SQL Server performance: full index on a table worth it?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Today I just read some comments and I made some experiment. I imagined a system which storing some coordinates.

Here is the situation:

I have two tables, the first is:

```
CREATE TABLE Points
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
X int,
Y int,
Name varchar(20),
Created datetime
)
```

It is just storing coordinates (1 million rows). The second one is a helper table storing some let's say often used points for a select (around 1100 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE PointSearchHelper
(
X int,
Y int
)
```

So far so fine.

I would like to make an easy select:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Points p 
INNER JOIN PointSearchHelper h
ON p.X = h.X AND p.Y = h.Y
```

I run the script, it gets the 1100 rows in around **280 ms** on average.

When I check the execution plan I see, that the SQL Server 2008 R2 recommends an index (who would have thought? ;) ) :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Points] ([X], [Y])
INCLUDE ([ID], [Name], [Created])
```

This one is a **full index** on the table, contains each column. It's size is "huge" comparing, that I'm storing the data now two times!

So the query no is much faster! It is around **75 ms**(!) Very great improvement **BUT** I need almost *double space* for this improvement.

**My question** is simple: Is there any way to tell the SQL Server on the columns how to store the values or any other trick to save yourself from a double storage?

UPDATE:

With other words: is there any trick to avoid the "full index" with the same performance?

Comment: I don't know is it worth or not to be posted in SQL Fiddle, but if somebody needs some script I can do that.

Comment: I think the best is try it with a lot of records (like 70.000), to compare space on disk against performance

Comment: The index is worth it especially if the performance gain is significant. Storage is cheap.

Comment: Many developers get their boxers in a bunch about wasting space when they should be concerned about maintainability and performance.  If you are running on a platform with more resources than a smart phone then investing a few extra megabytes of storage to achieve a large increase in performance is probably a wise tradeoff.  Not using `SELECT *` is generally wise for maintainability.

Comment: I know that it is cheap but why do I need to double sized the space, why can't I use onece stored data step to achive the same performace. That's what I would like to know. May there is a trick what I don't know.

Comment: No, there is no trick. Either you want the performance and are willing to pay the price of additional space usage - or your space is too important to you, then you have to live with less performance.... it's the classic **size-vs-speed** tradeoff - you get to pick either one - but only one of the two at the same time. Pick the one more important to you.

Comment: Just store the Points.Id in the second table, as a primary key not null.  You will save both space and processing time.

Comment: No it is not a tipical question, because f.e. Gordon's answer did the trick what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PointSearchHelper table to just use the index rather than the x, y coordinates:

```
create table PointSearchHelper . . .
    points_id int not null primary key
```

When you do the join, do it on points_id instead.  This should reduce space and increase performance.

PS.  I'm having the weirdest problem.  Adding an open paren to the code is causing an error in loading the anwer.

Comment: Very intresting Gordon! That seems will solve my question. It is very intresting to compare this one column PK with the X+Y PK solution. Because it did the trick, and the other one did not help at all. Do you have idea why?

Comment: Does this mean that it'll be a One-to-One relationship for Points and PointSearchHelper tables?

Comment: @koderoid . . . This statement would be one-to-(0,1).  To get 1-1, you would need a constraint guaranteeing that PointSearchHelper.points_id is indeed a valid key in Points.

Comment: I see. Will it still be joined by X, Y fields on both tables? I think I am missing something.

Comment: @koderoid . . . Each coordinate pair is mapped to a particular primary key in the POINTs table.  This has a primary key that identifies the point, but is only related to the X and Y coordinates through POINTS.

Comment: this means that Points.Point_Id must match PointSearchHelper.Point_Id right?

Comment: Got it. Thank you. If that's the case, will he benefit if he remove the X, Y fields on PointSearchHelper table and just store Point_Id? This will save storage space too.

Answer (score 1):

Are your X+Y pairs unique?
If they are, you might consider dropping the identity column and creating a composite primary key on the X+Y pairs.  That would remove the need for the additional index and might speed up your query even more.

Comment: I tried it but here is the problem, that a PK on X+Y, even those are unique pairs much slover then a simple PK on Identity column ID

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on other queries against this table, but if you did not want to have the full index, you could remove the primary key from ID, and instead place the primary key (and the clustered index) on `(X, Y)`

Doing this would store the data in the table by X and Y values, so this particular query would be faster, and only need to use the newly created clustered index.

You would have to look for potential problems with performance this might create if you have queries against your `Points` table that use the ID in `WHERE` clause, as this column will no longer be stored sorted ASC as it is now.  If you see that the majority of your queries are querying this table by X, Y values, you could test this change in a development server and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Hi! Thanks the reply. It seems your Primary Key change idea did not helped, but a simple primary key did it... Do you have idea why is the big differenc between X + Y as PK or ID as PK ?

Answer (score 1):

What result do you get when you create the index without INCLUDEing the non-key values?  It may be close to the speed you get with the full index.

Additionally, if the X, Y coordinates are guaranteed unique in Points then you could consider dropping the ID column and creating the primary key directly on (X, Y).  This will save you some space and also the overhead of indexing that column.

Comment: If you remove the include part of the index and select those values, you are apt to get a bookmark lookup.  That could be worse than the extra space.

Comment: Unfortunatly it did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I thougth easier to answer here for the answers, because I made the "homework", and I'm surprised:

**First:**

Changeing the **INDEX without INCLUEDED non-key values** -> It does not help, performance is around the 280 ms, like the normal one without the Full Index.

**Second:**

**Drop the ID column** make **X + Y as the primary key** (Let say those points are unique) and make an *other primary key index on the PointSearchHelper table on X + Y*. That solution surprised me, because then the Execution plan used both index, but the speed was also around 280 ms. So it **did not helped at all**.

**Third:**

Droping the ID of storing X and Y, let say making some logic around it when I save the values I checking what is the primary key ID of those records. 
With this there is only two index, again two primary key index on Points and PointHelperSearch. (I can see both of them in the exectuin plan, those are used. )
And it **did it**!! The speed was around 60-70 ms. So here is the trick.

Now, I'm wondering what is the differenc between *Second* and *Third*. Is it count so many ms, that there is two number instead of one?